# Sequential Game Rollback Equilibria Question

Tags: game-theory

[image: This is the problem.]

For this question, I believe Albus has 3 strategies: N, E, and S, and Minerva has 8: aaa, aab, aba, abb, baa, bab, bba, and bbb.
I've also found the rollback equilibrium to be the case in which Albus chooses N and Minerva chooses b. However, I'm not sure how to represent this equilibrium (equilibria?).

Do we say that the *unique* equilibrium is simply (N, b), since those are the choices made by the players, or do we say there are 4 equilibria: (N, baa), (N, bab), (N, bba), (N, bbb) since Minerva's choices are in reality a set of strategies, all of which result in her choosing b in response to Albus playing N?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct on the definition of the strategies: Albus' strategy set is $S_{A} = \big\{N,E,S\big\}$, and Minerva's is $S_{M} = \big\{a, b\big\} \times \big\{a, b\big\} \times \big\{a, b\big\}$.

Remember, a strategy is a *contingent plan* that prescribes an action at every possible node at which a player plays.

Then, the unique equilibrium (via Backward Induction) is $(N, b, a, b)$. The others you mention are not equilibria, because they involve *incredible threats*, e.g. if Minerva found herself at the decision node following a choice of $E$ by Albus, she would never choose $b$.